# Is the 'default' calendar in Google Calendar unique?

Tags: google-calendar

What I have noticed is that in the settings section for one of my calendars, that
(1) I am listed explicitly as the owner, and
(2) at the bottom of the settings for this calendar, there is only an option to 'Remove' the calendar.

I've also noticed that for any additional calendars that I create using the "Create a new calendar" interface:
(1) I am not explicitly listed as the owner, and
(2) at the bottom of the settings for any of these additional calendars, there is not only an option to 'Remove' but also an option to 'Unsubscribe'.

Why is a single calendar behaving differently? I can't seem to find any documentation that Google Calendar has a 'default' or 'primary' calendar, but it seems like it does.

Does anyone have insights into this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Calendar has a concept of a "default" calendar - it is known as the "Primary" calendar.

The [Calendar Service documentation] is described as "allow[ing] a script to access and modify the user's Google Calendar, **including** additional calendars that the user is subscribed to." (emphasis added)

It's probably true that the run-of-the-mill documentation doesn't spell this out, though one might suggest that an end-user is interested only in "their own" calendar, and that they understand that they can create or subscribe to other calendars.

The [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts) has more information including this self-explanatory image.

[image: screenshot]

The detailed API documentation describes the [Primary Calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#primary_calendars_and_other_calendars) as follows:

> A primary calendar is a special type of calendar associated with a single user account. This calendar is created automatically for each new user account and its ID usually matches the user's primary email address. As long as the account exists, its primary calendar can never be deleted or "un-owned" by the user. However, it can still be shared with other users.
>
> In addition to the primary calendar, you can explicitly create any number of other calendars; these calendars can be modified, deleted, and shared among multiple users.

Comment: Thank you, Tedinoz! This is _exactly_ what I was looking for. The official developers.google.com/<app> documentation is hugely beneficial; I will be using it quite often going forward.